# Directly verify ring axioms for a ring with $2$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, formal-proofs

I'm relearning mathematics from the ground up in order to keep up with it's rigor in the university I attend. I'm doing this with serge langs basic mathematics, which thankfully involves writing proofs as well. The exercise is to let E be an abbreviation for even, and let I be an abbreviation for odd.
Then you're given as a given:

```
     E + E = E
     E + I = I + E = I
     I + I = E
     EE = E
     II = I
     IE = EI = E
```

Then asked that you

```
 Show that addition for E and I is associative and commutative.
 Show that E plays the role if a zero element for addition. What is the additive inverse of E?
 What is the additive inverse of I.
 Show that multiplication for E and I is commutative and associative.
 Which behaves like 0 for multiplication? 
 Show that multiplication is distributive with respect to addition.
```

I think i've answered these with something along the lines of

```
(E + I) + I = E + (I + I)
(I + E) + I = I + (E + I)
```

which I believe is technically correct but could probably be better expressed as something like

```
E + E + E = E + E = E = E + E = E + E + E
```

actually shows I associativity. you'd just commit to the same task for all different possible equations.
commutativity looks like

```
E + E = E = E + E
```

`what i'm confused about is how to understand this in such a case as`

```
(EI)I = EI = E = II = I = E(II)
```

`Which i've been led to believe is correct. However the question arises from what the equation seems to convey. How can E = II in the associated multiplicative case? E is almost like a representation of zero isnt it. I think i'm fundamentally misunderstanding something about proofs.`

Comment: The product of two odd numbers is an odd number,  not an even number.

Comment: $II=I$ from the givens.

Comment: Writing a sum of three elements without using parentheses assumes you’ve already established associativity. So it’s definitely not better than writing correct things.

Comment: @lulu so how can E which is even be equal to the product of two odd numbers? Isnt that essentially what that's (E = II) attempting to say?

Comment: Where did you get $E=I\times I$?  That is clearly false, and isn't one of your axioms.

Comment: @lulu that's what I said. A nice man demonstrated an attempt at writing proofs elsewhere on here so I decided to beg the question as I didnt think that was correct. Is it possible to give a an example of the right way to convey associativity in the case of EII

Comment: It isn't correct.  And checking associativity case by case is sensible here as there are very few cases.  For instance:  $(E\times I)\times I=E\times I=E$ and $E\times (I\times I)=E\times I=E$ so $E\times I\times I$ is well-defined (I wouldn't write it that way until you have checked associativity though).

Comment: @lulu i was still confused but then it clicked that I x I is still I which makes E x I = E. Makes sense. thank you, however doesn't this already demonstrate associativity?

Comment: It demonstrates it for the triple $E\times I\times I$.  There are other triples.  It's easy, however, if you note that the only triple that gives an odd number is $I\times I\times I$.